# Modal popup opening in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

**JavaScript**:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function example() {
        alert("dfszgvf");
        $find('Something').show();
    }
</script>
```

**C#**:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "JsStatus", "example();", true);
}
```

**ASPX**:

```html
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"  runat="server" 
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBg" DropShadow="true" 
    PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel2" CancelControlID="btnCancel" 
    TargetControlID="lnkUpdate" OkControlID="btnOK" PopupControlID="Panel1"
    BehaviorID ="Something">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" ForeColor="#0000ff" Font-Bold="true" 
            Font-Underline="true" Font-Size="12px" runat="server">Click here to Change Text Style</asp:LinkButton>   
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPanel" Style="display: none">
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" style="border:solid 2px #cccccc; width:98%; cursor: move;">Drag Panel
     <div>
     ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
     </div>
       <div class="right">
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="[ X ]" />
        </div>
        <div class="left">
        <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK Client Side" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
```

`ModalPopupExtender` works when I use a link button, but it is not working when called from `.cs` code (in c#).

Can anyone help me to resolve the error?....................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What do you mean not working? Can you provide the error message? Console Errors?

Comment: Same works fine for link button.but C# code does

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a **`BehaviorID`** for modal popup:

```html
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"  runat="server" 
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBg" DropShadow="true" 
    PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel2" CancelControlID="btnCancel" 
    TargetControlID="lnkUpdate" OkControlID="btnOK" PopupControlID="Panel1"
    BehaviorID ="Something">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Then use:

```js
var id= '<%= ModalPopupExtender1.BehaviorID %>';
$find('id').show();
```

Comment: It gives error that ModalPopupExtender does not have a public proprty named as 'behavourid'

Comment: Sorry still i am having= same problem,modal popup not showing

Comment: Can you the provide code by editing your question..I can check?

Comment: I added updated code.Thank you sir,for your concern.

Comment: Do you use masterpage in your website?I hope the case is behaviorID is changing on client side..Try updated answer,Regards..

Comment: Presently no..future i think to use masterpage